# Why is my Auth0 access token truncated in Windows systems but not on Mac OS?

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, auth0, user-management

I am using **Auth0** in my NextJS web application and attempting to retrieve an access token using the getAccessTokenSilently function. However, when I use this function on a Windows system, the access token that is returned is truncated and cannot be verified. Interestingly, when I use the same Auth0 credentials on a Mac OS system, the getAccessTokenSilently function works perfectly fine and returns a valid access token.

What could be causing this discrepancy in behavior between the two operating systems? Has anyone else experienced this issue with Auth0 on Windows systems? How can I ensure that the access token returned on a Windows system is not truncated and can be properly verified? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is a screenshot from the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXR26.jpg)

I tried using a mac system and it worked perfectly but when using a windows os it is sending a truncated access token. And also I tried every possible way which it can be solved but no result.

Comment: There's seem to be such issue on their [forum](https://community.auth0.com/t/access-token-is-not-valid-and-is-truncated/96422) but no answers there. I also never use such services as I always build auth my own way, but for any other user that had used it you may want to provide some code.